# Flutter Building eror

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

[Code home_view.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEhVy.jpg) 
[main.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0MK9.jpg)

ib/app/routes/app_pages.dart:18:25: Error: Couldn't find constructor 'HomeView'. page: () => const HomeView(), ^^^^^^^^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where: Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1297

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 8s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I want to run the flutter app but this is what happened, it's been 1 week and I haven't found the answer can help me?

Comment: Hi, if you have found the solution, it's better to write a regular answer. This may help someone else with a similar /same problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `flutter clean` and then installing the packages again and then running the app?

Comment: i was try, its not working

Comment: The issue is that you have not created a component with `HomePage()` or if you have not imported the package in the file that you are calling in that is why it is causing the issue

Comment: the answer that worked for me
> **I've found the answer, thank you. simply remove the const in the ib/app/routes/app_pages.dart section**

Answer (score 0):

This error is for flutter codes and is not for android or gradle.
Be sure to pay attention to the error that is thrown before this error.